# Rails: How to restrict signup to admin using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to restrict signups to a Devise admin. If possible, I would like to avoid using CanCan for now. I have created a separate Devise Admin model as described in option #1 here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role.

Next, I set up a CRUD interface for users as described here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface.

I would like to restrict new signups by using something like `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` in the Users controller, but for some reason it is not restricting new signups.

My routes.rb looks like this:

```
devise_for :admins
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :admins
resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

Any ideas why `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` is not restricting new signups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` in Users controller because admin and user are two different models in your app.

I don't know if I fully understand what you mean, but you can do this if you don't want to accept new registrations for User (or Admin):

```
# in your User(Admin) model
devise :registerable # remove :registerable
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should be able to use `before_filter :authenticate_admin!` when you add an Admin role. This is currently working for me on a Users index and show action (for managing users as admin). I'm not sure why it's not working on the create action. I don't want to remove :registerable because I want Admins to be able to add users.

Comment: Hi Scott, you need not define a new `create` action. If you look inside the source code of devise, you'll find in `app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb` devise has done everything for you, besides those actions, `authenticate_scope!` which is an abstract method for `authenticate_admin!` in your case, is prepended and only works for **`edit destroy update`** these three actions. If you really want to add `authenticate_admin!` filter to create action, you can inherit from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and add `prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :except => [:cancel]`.

Comment: I decided that this became too complicated only using devise, so I added CanCan, which worked great. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar; disabling new registrations altogether. I dug this up on a mailing list somewhere and while it solved my problem it might be a decent starting point for yours:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  def new
    flash[:failure] = t('registrations.registrations_disabled')
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Maybe something similar but add a check to see if the current_user is an admin then redirect based on that...

Answer (score 2):

I pondered about this for a while and finally came up with this.

There is a helper function for every model created by devise

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  def new
    if admin_signed_in?
      super
    else
      redirect_to admin_session_path
    end
   end
```

Hope this helps. It works like a charm :)

Comment: This was super helpful. But I used `before_action :authenticate_admin!`
 and not `before_filter :authenticate_admin!`. Thank you.